# How can I configure TLS1.1 on LFTP?

Tags: linux, ssl, lftp

I need to configure `TLS1.1` for `lftp`?Also how can I check which version of `TLS` is running on my Redhat Linux OS ?

Comment: What configuration did you try and what issues did you have?

Comment: Please find below the config:

/usr/local/bin/lftp -d
open -p 20990 -u test,test ftps://ftpssl.google.com set ftp:ssl-allow true set ftp:ssl-force true set ftp:ssl-protect-data true set ftp:ssl-protect-list true debug 13 cd outbound/HV

Error when using /usr/local/bin/lftp (openssl library) lftp

Iam putting the error logs in pasty: .http://pastie.org/10736829

Answer (score 1):

From the [`lftp` man page](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html), it looks like the `lftp` setting needed for configuring the TLS protocol version is `ssl:priority`.  Thus you might try the following:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/lftp -d open -p 20990 -u test,test ftps://ftpssl.google.com 
lftp> set ftp:ssl-allow true
lftp> set ftp:ssl-force true
lftp> set ftp:ssl-protect-data true
lftp> set ftp:ssl-protect-list true
lftp> set ssl:priority NORMAL:+VERS-TLS1.1:+VERS-TLS1.2
lftp> debug 13
lftp> cd outbound/HV
```

Note the additional setting of `ssl:priority`; the values depend on whether your `lftp` was compiled using OpenSSL or GnuTLS.  Since your output indicated GnuTLS, the above example shows the [GnuTLS priority string](https://gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Priority-Strings.html) value.